# Can work system admin remote into my personal Mac when I connect to work VPN?

Tags: vpn, macos, remote-desktop

I usually connect to my work VPN on my personal Mac and then use Windows Remote Desktop client to access my work computer.

Today on my Mac while disconnected from the VPN I noticed the `username/machine` that usually shows up in the terminal as this:
`myusername@macbook-pro ~`

was showing as
`worksystemadmin@workcomputer ~`

[image]

where `worksystemadmin` is the username of the system admin at work
and `workcomputer` is a computer on the work network

could it be possible that he got access to my Mac?

Comment: Ah, that's a common problem. Nothing is wrong. I'll link a duplicate that explains it.

Comment: Lots of explaination over at: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40734/why-is-my-host-name-wrong-at-the-terminal-prompt-when-connected-to-a-public-wifi

Comment: thanks... that's exactly what I was looking for.